# Member Badges/Achievement?

Tags: members, solspace, plugin, solspace-user

Had anyone come across developing **Member badges** in Expressionengine?

I am developing a site, when a member do such activities such as

- Creating Entry
- Leaving Ratings
- Leaving Comments
- Making 10x comments
- etc

and they get awarded a badge.

**Plugins I am using**

- User (Solspace)
- Credits (Dev Demon)

I need some guidance. If no such plugins available, is there any other alternative I could develop with.

Many thanks
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never done that but there are a few Member custom profile options available, see http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/member/index.html#id6

That would cover, for each member, getting

- Total entries
- Total comments
- Total forums posts
- Total forum topics

You could grab those values and do somthing like:

```
{exp:member:custom_profile_data}
    {if total_entries < 10}Newbie user{/if}
    {if total_entries >= 10 AND total_entries < 50}Advanced user{/if}
    {if total_entries >= 50}Super user{/if}
{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```

Comment: Looks like a good idea, will let you know how it goes.